# Data showing what JavaScript operations are usable in what browser

Tags: data-request, standards, programming, internet

I am looking for compatibility data about browsers:

- Does browser `Firefox 32` support `createDocumentFragment()`?
- Does browser `Internet Explorer 5.5` support `querySelectorAll()`?
- etc

Data should be easily downloadable under an open license, unlike [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/core/).
*(for instance for use in an open source IDE or quality insurance tool)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) project includes compatabilities for many browsers versus CSS, HTML, JS API, SVG, and Other categories.

> "Can I use" provides up-to-date browser support tables for support of front-end web technologies on desktop and mobile web browsers.

License is [CC BY-NC 3.0](http://caniuse.com/#info_about).

Raw data is on [GitHub](https://github.com/fyrd/caniuse).